# How to speed up copying values from sheet to sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I want to copy values from a sheet to use that sheet to calculate the result.

There is a lot of back and forth. Is there a way to speed this up?

I tried some other optimisation methods but I hope it can run faster.

```
Sub design()

Dim MFrow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

MFrow = 4

Do Until MFrow = 208
    'Application.Calculation = xlManual
            
    'from Summary to Design
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("I" & MFrow & ":" & "M" & MFrow).Copy
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("O11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("P" & MFrow & ":" & "T" & MFrow).Copy
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("P11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    
    'from Summary to Design
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("R35:T35").Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("W" & MFrow & ":" & "y" & MFrow).Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("R36:T36").Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("AB" & MFrow & ":" & "AD" & MFrow).Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("R37:T37").Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("AG" & MFrow & ":" & "AI" & MFrow).Value
            
    'Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    
    'from Design to Summary
    Range("ETABS_U").Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("C" & MFrow)
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("D" & MFrow).Value = Range("End1Mu").Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("E" & MFrow).Value = Range("MidMu").Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("F" & MFrow).Value = Range("End2Mu").Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("G" & MFrow).Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("F24")
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("H" & MFrow).Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("H23")
    
    'from Design to Summary
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("O28:O29").Copy
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("N" & MFrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("P28:P29").Copy
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("U" & MFrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    
    'from Design to Summary
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("Z" & MFrow & ":" & "AA" & MFrow).Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("Y35:Z35").Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("AE" & MFrow & ":" & "AF" & MFrow).Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("Y36:Z36").Value
    Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("AJ" & MFrow & ":" & "AK" & MFrow).Value = Worksheets("Frame Beam Design").Range("Y37:Z37").Value

    MFrow = MFrow + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code pastes I4:M4 transposed to O11 on the other sheet, 200 times with different source rows. O11:O15 will be changed 200 times but will only show the values of  I204:M204. Same for P4:T4 and P11:P15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the following comment above, "Your code pastes I4:M4 transposed to O11 on the other sheet, 200 times with different source rows. O11:O15 will be changed 200 times but will only show the values of I204:M204. Same for P4:T4 and P11:P15.' This logical error runs throughout your code. Or perhaps there is something I don't understand, such as formulas that are pasted or working in the background so that the same cells get different values with each loop.

The key to making code run faster is to reduce the number of times it reads from  a sheet or writes to it. You can read an entire sheet into an array in much the same time as a single value. Similarly, you can write thousands of values in the same time as just one. My code makes use of these facts. It reads a range of values, converts these values to a transposed array in memory and then pastes that new array to the target area. It's very fast. Please take note of the constant `LastRow` at the top. I tested the code with just 14 rows and you may want to do the same. However, in your project the number is `204`. Please adjust it in the code.

```
Sub Design()
    ' 128

    Const FirstRow      As Long = 4
    Const LastRow       As Long = 14
    
    Dim WsDes           As Worksheet        ' Worksheets("Frame Beam Design")
    Dim WsSum           As Worksheet        ' Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary")
    Dim ArrS            As Variant          ' intermediate storage of Source range's value
    Dim ArrT            As Variant          ' intermediate storage of Targe range's value
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    Dim C               As Long             ' loop counter: columns
    Dim Cstart          As Long             ' start columns of second source groups relative to first
    Dim Ct              As Long             ' Column in ArrT
    Dim i               As Long             ' loop counter: ArrS(index)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False             ' useful
        .EnableEvents = False               ' useful if you have event procedures
        .Calculation = xlManual             ' of doubtful benefit here
    End With

    Set WsDes = Worksheets("Frame Beam Design")
    Set WsSum = Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary")
    
    With WsSum
        ArrS = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, "I"), .Cells(LastRow, "T")).Value
        Cstart = .Columns("P").Column - .Columns("I").Column
    End With
    ' create an array with 5 rows and twice as many columns as ArrS has rows
    ReDim ArrT(1 To 5, 1 To UBound(ArrS) * 2)
    Ct = 1
    For R = LBound(ArrS) To UBound(ArrS)
        For i = 0 To Cstart Step Cstart
            For C = 1 To 5
                ArrT(C, Ct) = ArrS(R, C + i)
            Next C
            Ct = Ct + 1
        Next i
    Next R
    WsDes.Cells(11, "O").Resize(UBound(ArrT), UBound(ArrT, 2)).Value = ArrT
    
    With WsSum
        ArrS = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, "W"), .Cells(LastRow, "AI")).Value
        Cstart = .Columns("AB").Column - .Columns("w").Column
    End With
    ' create an array with 3 rows and thrice as many columns as ArrS has rows
    ReDim ArrT(1 To 3, 1 To UBound(ArrS) * 3)
    Ct = 1
    For R = LBound(ArrS) To UBound(ArrS)
        For i = 0 To (Cstart * 2) Step Cstart
            For C = 1 To 3
                ArrT(C, Ct) = ArrS(R, C + i)
            Next C
            Ct = Ct + 1
        Next i
    Next R
    WsDes.Cells(35, "R").Resize(UBound(ArrT), UBound(ArrT, 2)).Value = ArrT
   
    'from Design to Summary
    With WsDes
        ' not clear, why you want to change these ranges 200 times
        ' just to display the value in WsSum.Cells(LastRow, [Clm])
        .Range("ETABS_U").Value = WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "C")
        .Range("End1Mu").Value = WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "D")
        .Range("MidMu").Value = WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "E")
        .Range("End2Mu").Value = WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "F")
        .Cells(24, "F").Value = WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "G")
        .Cells(23, "H").Value = WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "H")
    
        .Range("O28:O29").Copy
        WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "N").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        .Range("P28:P29").Copy
        WsSum.Cells(LastRow, "U").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    End With

    'from Design to Summary
    WsSum.Range("Z" & R & ":" & "AA" & R).Value = WsDes.Range("Y35:Z35").Value
    WsSum.Range("AE" & R & ":" & "AF" & R).Value = WsDes.Range("Y36:Z36").Value
    WsSum.Range("AJ" & R & ":" & "AK" & R).Value = WsDes.Range("Y37:Z37").Value
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

In the first two sections of the code I resolved the repetition of the target cells by extending the columns to the right. The important part of my code is to create the arrays, which is done correctly. How to write them to the sheet is just a minor adjustment. I hope you can do it.

My method didn't work for the named ranges in section 3 of your procedure because I don't know their size. I slightly modified your syntax but didn't offer a solution to the problem. The last section is just a repetition of 1 and 2, slightly modified, and I think you should be able to replicate whatever suits you in the earlier sections.

One piece of advice, if I may: Don't address cells as "ranges". The correct syntax is `Ws.Cells([Row number], [Column number of name])`. Ranges are addressed by their names, which are strings. Excel provides default names which it concatenates using cell coordinates. This is an extremely cumbersome process to replicate in code, as you have found. Instead of creating a string which VBA then converts into numbers (after you concatenated the numbers into the string), define a range by its first and last cells, like, `Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(14, 7))` which is equivalent to B1:G14 or `Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(14, "G"))` or *Range("B" & 2 & ":G"& 14)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Since you are using Do loop, if possible try to avoid copy paste method and use .value method like you in your code

" Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary").Range("D" & MFrow).Value = Range("End1Mu").Value"

2) After every copy paste method, try the below code to remove clip board memory

Application.cutcopymode =false
Application.cutcopymode= true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Loop With Recalculation

- Hard to tell without knowing the exact formulas in the cells, but this might be of use.
- Play with `Calculate`, maybe out-comment it on the first run to see if there is any difference in efficiency (out-comment `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` also). Use common sense to figure out what is supposed to be calculated at which point. I just made a guess. The solution might be totally different.
- This is rarely done in this way, so think about rewriting the whole thing without it depending on formulas in the loop i.e. VBA can do what the formulas are doing and it would probably take a second or so to finish. Off course, cannot not know for sure without seeing the whole setup.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub design()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "design"
    ' If you start getting error messages in the Immediate window,
    ' then out-comment the following line to see where the error is occurring.
    ' When the problem is solved, uncomment the line.
    On Error GoTo clearError

    Const MFrow As Long = 4
    Const LFrow As Long = 207
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim smr As Worksheet
    Set smr = wb.Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary")
    Dim des As Worksheet
    Set des = wb.Worksheets("Frame Beam Design")
    
    ' 5 cells
    Dim s1 As Range: Set s1 = smr.Columns("I:M")
    Dim d1 As Range: Set d1 = des.Range("O11").Resize(s1.Columns.Count)
    Dim s2 As Range: Set s2 = smr.Columns("P:T")
    Dim d2 As Range: Set d2 = des.Range("P11").Resize(s2.Columns.Count)
    ' 3 cells
    Dim s3_1 As Range: Set s3_1 = smr.Columns("W:Y")
    Dim s3_2 As Range: Set s3_2 = smr.Columns("AB:AD")
    Dim s3_3 As Range: Set s3_3 = smr.Columns("AG:AI")
    Dim d3 As Range: Set d3 = des.Range("R35:T37")
    ' 1 cell
    Dim s4 As Range: Set s4 = smr.Columns("C:H")
    ' 2 cells
    Dim s5 As Range: Set s5 = smr.Columns("N:O")
    Dim d5 As Range: Set d5 = des.Range("O28").Resize(s1.Columns.Count)
    Dim s6 As Range: Set s6 = smr.Columns("U:V")
    Dim d6 As Range: Set d6 = des.Range("P28").Resize(s1.Columns.Count)
    ' 2 cells
    Dim s7_1 As Range: Set s7_1 = smr.Columns("Z:AA")
    Dim s7_2 As Range: Set s7_2 = smr.Columns("AE:AF")
    Dim s7_3 As Range: Set s7_3 = smr.Columns("AJ:AK")
    Dim d7 As Range: Set d7 = des.Range("Y35:Z37")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = MFrow To LFrow
        
        'from Summary to Design
        d1.Value = Application.Transpose(s1.Rows(i).Value)
        d2.Value = Application.Transpose(s2.Rows(i).Value)
        d3.Rows(1).Value = s3_1.Rows(i).Value
        d3.Rows(2).Value = s3_2.Rows(i).Value
        d3.Rows(3).Value = s3_3.Rows(i).Value
        
        ' Maybe
        des.Calculate
        ' Or just:
'        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
'        DoEvents
'        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       
        'from Design to Summary
        Range("ETABS_U").Value = s4.Cells(i, 1).Value
        s4.Cells(i, 2).Value = Range("End1Mu").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("MidMu").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 4).Value = Range("End2Mu").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 5).Value = des.Range("F24").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 6).Value = des.Range("H23").Value
       
        'from Design to Summary
        s5.Rows(i).Value = Application.Transpose(d5.Value)
        s6.Rows(i).Value = Application.Transpose(d6.Value)
        
        'from Design to Summary
        s3_1.Rows(i).Value = d3.Rows(1).Value
        s3_2.Rows(i).Value = d3.Rows(2).Value
        s3_3.Rows(i).Value = d3.Rows(3).Value

        ' Maybe
        smr.Calculate
        
    Next i

ProcExit:
    
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who contribute this! This is great. I have revised a little but it is  a lot faster now!

```
Option Explicit

Sub design()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "design"
    ' If you start getting error messages in the Immediate window,
    ' then out-comment the following line to see where the error is occurring.
    ' When the problem is solved, uncomment the line.
    On Error GoTo clearError

    Dim MFrow, LFrow As Integer
         
    MFrow = Range("Starti").Value
    LFrow = Range("Endi").Value
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim smr As Worksheet
    Set smr = wb.Worksheets("Frame Beam Summary")
    Dim des As Worksheet
    Set des = wb.Worksheets("Frame Beam Design")
    
    ' 5 cells
    Dim s1 As Range: Set s1 = smr.Columns("I:M")
    Dim d1 As Range: Set d1 = des.Range("O11").Resize(s1.Columns.Count)
    Dim s2 As Range: Set s2 = smr.Columns("P:T")
    Dim d2 As Range: Set d2 = des.Range("P11").Resize(s2.Columns.Count)
    ' 3 cells
    Dim s3_1 As Range: Set s3_1 = smr.Columns("W:Y")
    Dim s3_2 As Range: Set s3_2 = smr.Columns("AB:AD")
    Dim s3_3 As Range: Set s3_3 = smr.Columns("AG:AI")
    Dim d3 As Range: Set d3 = des.Range("R35:T37")
    ' 1 cell
    Dim s4 As Range: Set s4 = smr.Columns("C:H")
    ' 2 cells
    Dim s5 As Range: Set s5 = smr.Columns("N:O")
    Dim d5 As Range: Set d5 = des.Range("O28").Resize(s1.Columns.Count)
    Dim s6 As Range: Set s6 = smr.Columns("U:V")
    Dim d6 As Range: Set d6 = des.Range("P28").Resize(s1.Columns.Count)
    ' 2 cells
    Dim s7_1 As Range: Set s7_1 = smr.Columns("Z:AA")
    Dim s7_2 As Range: Set s7_2 = smr.Columns("AE:AF")
    Dim s7_3 As Range: Set s7_3 = smr.Columns("AJ:AK")
    Dim d7_1 As Range: Set d7_1 = des.Range("Y35:Z35")
    Dim d7_2 As Range: Set d7_2 = des.Range("Y36:Z36")
    Dim d7_3 As Range: Set d7_3 = des.Range("Y37:Z37")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = MFrow To LFrow
        
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then
        
            Application.StatusBar = i & "/" & LFrow - MFrow
        
        End If
        
        Range("ETABS_U").Value = s4.Cells(i, 1).Value
              
        'from Summary to Design
        d1.Value = Application.Transpose(s1.Rows(i).Value)
        d2.Value = Application.Transpose(s2.Rows(i).Value)
        
        
        d3.Rows(1).Value = s3_1.Rows(i).Value
        d3.Rows(2).Value = s3_2.Rows(i).Value
        d3.Rows(3).Value = s3_3.Rows(i).Value
        
        ' Maybe
        'des.Calculate
        ' Or just:
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        DoEvents
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       
        'from Design to Summary
        
        s4.Cells(i, 2).Value = Range("End1Mu").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("MidMu").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 4).Value = Range("End2Mu").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 5).Value = des.Range("F24").Value
        s4.Cells(i, 6).Value = des.Range("H23").Value
       
        'from Design to Summary
        s5.Rows(i).Value = Application.Transpose(d5.Value)
        s6.Rows(i).Value = Application.Transpose(d6.Value)
        
        'from Design to Summary

        s7_1.Rows(i).Value = d7_1.Value
        s7_2.Rows(i).Value = d7_2.Value
        s7_3.Rows(i).Value = d7_3.Value

        ' Maybe
        'smr.Calculate
        
        
        
    Next i

ProcExit:
    
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```